# How can use a property later in the rxjs observable stream?

Tags: rxjs

I send a request to a server and got a response with a body and a cookies property

```
{body:[row1,...,rowN], cookies:sessionData}
```

in the next step i want to transform the data to match my needs

in (1) there is the `res` object that includes the above structure, `res` is at (2) no longer valid of course, because it's another scope. Is there a rx-way to deal with it and get cookies later or have I implement a structure in the first mapping (1) where I include the cookies? in the streamed data?

```
this.sendRequest("find",params) // send request with some query parameters
      .map((res:Library.Response) => JSON.parse(res.body)) // (1) get the parsed body
      .map((data) => this.filterFindings(data)) // get only the good ones
      .map((data) => this.addCookies(data, res.cookies) // (2) want to add the cookies from res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest your call to keep the response in scope:

```
this.sendRequest(...).pipe(
  switchMap(res => of(res).pipe(
    map(res => JSON.parse(res.body)),
    //... 
    map(data => addCookies(data, res.cookies)) 
  )
);
```

Comment: works. feels reactive. I know there is a simple solution. thank you.